# miner.stop() returns null does not stop mining on private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain

I am using Version: 1.9.0-unstable of geth, and I noticed miner.stop() does not work anymore. I am sure it always worked.

```
> eth.blockNumber
901069
> miner.stop()
null
> eth.blockNumber
901130
```

miner.start() returned null but miner.stop() always returned true, but it is returning null. I am running private net. Any ideas?

Comment: It is better to report thing that broke with a new version to geth repo https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues.